How to get a binary to run under a specific toolchain when called from a build.rs?
Context
I am trying to build a binary wrapper around rustgpu which is to be called from a build.rs script of a different rust binary.
The caller crate, call it Parent uses toolchain a, the rustgpu wrapper wrapper uses toolchain b. Wrapper can only run under b due to restrictions rustgpu has.
Problem
It seems no matter what I do, the cargo config set up for the build.rs project overrides anything I try to do. For example, this is one attempt (in the wrapper code) to enforce the correct toolchain.
Things I have tried:

Adding a toolchain.toml to the directory from which the wrapper is run, this doesn;t work as cargo ignores the toolchain when run from within a build.rs script.
Running through rustup like this:

let output = Command::new("rustup")
        .arg("run")
        .arg("nightly-2024-01-08")
        .arg(relative_rust_builder_path)
        .arg("-i")
        .arg(relative_shader_path)
        .current_dir(cwd)
        .output()
        .unwrap();

But once more, seems like it is ignored by cargo.
Is it possible to have the parent crate (the one where the build.rs is defined) setup this properly so that invoking cargo through the build script uses the correct toolchain?

Try clearing the environment, or at least removing the CARGO_* variables.

Have you set a rustup override for wrapper's directory or an ancestor thereof?

@eggyal I have explicitely called rustup override with the toolchain I need for the wrapper but it still uses the wrong toolchain.
